# Changing settings for XFCE4 on debian wheezy terminal

Tags: debian, xfce, raspberry-pi, desktop, raspbian

I am using a raspberry pi running raspbian wheezy.
How do you change the desktop settings for an XFCE4 desktop on raspbian, installed with `sudo apt-get install xfce4-full`, now the default X desktop, without going into the desktop, i.e. over SSH? I am happy to install tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible using `xfconf-query` (I think it's  already installed on your system), but is not going to be convenient (there are a few hundred of properties, so finding the right one to edit wouldn't ever be fast). Official documentation is [here](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query).